# Understanding Heaviside and Dirac Delta for Quantum step function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

Looking at the solution for from this
[site](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/08/24/infinite-square-well-with-triangular-initial-state-using-delta-function/)
 I'm a bit confused on how two quantities necessarily reduce.

I'm given this wavefunction

$$ \psi(x) = \begin{cases} 
      Ax & 0<x<a/2  \\
      A(a-x) & a/2 < x < a \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

If I take the derivative, we can express it as a step function.

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial\ \psi(x)}{\partial x} &= \begin{cases} 
      A & 0<x<a/2  \\
      -A & a/2 < x < a \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} \\
&\\
&= A \left[ \theta(x) - \theta \left (x-\frac{a}{2} \right) - \theta \left( x-\frac{a}{2} \right) + \theta(x-a) \right] \, .
\end{align}

### First Question

How does the step function reduce to this?

$$ A \left[ \theta(x) - \theta \left(x-\frac{a}{2} \right) - \theta \left(x-\frac{a}{2} \right) + \theta(x-a) \right] = -A \left( 2 \theta \left(x-\frac{a}{2} \right) - 1 \right) \, ,
$$
i.e. where did the one come from?

So with that that quantity, I take second derivative to get

$$ \frac{\partial^2\ \psi(x)}{\partial^2 x} = -2A\ \delta \left(x-\frac{a}{2} \right) \, .$$

### Second Question

So now what is left is integrating my second derivative with my step function, in which I have no idea which terms vanish.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^{*} \frac{\partial^2\ \psi(x)}{\partial^2 x}dx = A \int_{0}^{a/2} x \delta(x-a/2) dx + A \int_{a/2}^{a} a \delta(x-a/2) dx - A \int_{a/2}^{a} x \delta(x-a/2) dx 
$$

How do I go about this and what is the reasoning?

Comment: The $1$ comes from the fact that $\theta(x)$ is $1$ in the interval from $0$ to a.  $\theta(x-a)$ only affects values for $x > a$, so it can be ignored in this interval.

Answer (score 1):

**First Question**
I guess your source is implicitly stating 'let's focus only on $ ] 0,a [ $'. You can leave the $\theta(x)$ and the $\theta(a-x)$, the corresponding deltas will vanish anyway (see below).

**Second Question**
I would say the way you wrote the integral miss some pieces:
$$\int_{0}^{a/2} \psi^{*} \frac{\partial^2\ \psi(x)}{\partial^2 x} \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{a/2} A x \cdot -2A\ \delta(x-\frac{a}{2}) \ \mathrm{d}x = A \int_{0}^{a/2} \delta(x-a/2) \ \mathrm{d} x \ \ ??$$
Etc.

Anyway, you can calculate the energy expectation value using directly the property of delta: $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \delta(x-c) \ \mathrm{d}x = f(c)$$
where $c \in \ ]x_1, x_2[$ (but you correctly wrote $]-\infty,\infty[$, so that's certainly true).

If you want, $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \delta(x-x_2) \ \mathrm{d}x = f(x_2) / 2$ etc, but it's simpler if you don't split the integral at all.

Comment: Hi, I defined the bounds of the integral from $[-\infty,\infty]$ to represent all space, which reduce to the bounds of the step function. For the integrals of $\int_{a/2}^{a} x \delta(x-a/2)dx + \int_{a/2}^{a} \delta(x-a/2)$, how would you evaluate it?

Comment: It gets tricky if you try to split the integral just in the delta evaluation point (but possible: divide the result by 2). Maybe I should add this in the answer.

Comment: @DarthLazar Did you manage to solve this? The only real problem I could see was about how to apply the Dirac delta (in the slightly improper way you'll always see in physics) and I tried to address that, but if there is something else please try to expand on it, because I can't figure it out by myself.